# How to design a database/table which adds a lot of rows every minute

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization

I am in the situation where I need to store data for 1900+ cryptocurrencies every minute, i use MySQL innoDB.

Currently, the table looks like this

```
coins_minute_id | coins_minute_coin_fk | coins_minute_usd | coins_minute_btc | coins_minute_datetime | coins_minute_timestamp

coins_minute_id = autoincrement id
coins_minute_coin_fk  = medium int unsigned
coins_minute_usd  = decimal 20,6
coins_minute_btc = decimal 20,8
coins_minute_datetime = datetime
coins_minute_timestamp = timestamp
```

The table grew incredibly fast in the matter of no time, every minute 1900+ rows are added to the table.

The data will be used for historical price display as a `D3.js` line graph for each cryptocurrency.

My question is how do i optimize this database the best, i have thought of only collecting the data every 5 minutes instead of 1, but it will still add up to a lot of data in no time, i have also thought if it was better to create a unique table for each cryptocurrency, does any of you who loves to design databases know some other very smart and clever way to do stuff like this?

Kindly Regards

(From Comment)

```
SELECT  coins_minute_coin_fk, coins_minute_usd
    FROM  coins_minutes
    WHERE  coins_minute_datetime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)
      AND  coins_minute_coin_fk <= 1000
    ORDER BY  coins_minute_coin_fk ASC
```

Comment: Partition the table by date (month or year) so that only partitions involved in the date ranges being looked at will be used in queries?  But this assumes that date will be used when searching on history.  or that and the type of currency so that each is different.   And what do you mean by "OPTIMIZE" for reads? Writes? what?

Comment: It's not only about the size of data, but also what kind of operations will you perform. E.g. will you need joins? Simple selects? How big are assumed returned datasets? Will you do aggregate queries (GROUP BY)? Paralel writes, or read/write? RDBMS vs. NOSQL? InnoDB would need quite a lot of tuning for such a huge data, I would not recommend it. I would recommend running some benchmarks before making any decision and also compare 2-3 alternatives like Aerospike, Cassandra, HBase or perhaps MariaDB with MyRocks engine.

Comment: @lubosdz, I will currently only need to do a simple select statement, I am using PDO, will I need to rewrite all my queries if I decide to change to etc MariaDB? the datasets will be between 1 week of data to 1 quarter of a year

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 I understand that you will collect data for up to 3 months and the delete it, right? Not storing forever. Then InnoDB could be perhaps also fine. MariaDB and mySQL are compatible in common queries. Unless you use specific features (windows, JSON, ..) you probably don't need to rewrite anything. Please note that mentioned myRocks engine (which is actually optimized InnoDB by FB) is currently experimental and needs extra installation - check with the online documentation.

Comment: @lubosdz correct, I might do the 5 minute or 2,3,4 minutes and then delete the data after 3 months, due to the fact that the historical (all) will not have minutes intervals but days instead and i have a whole different table for that part :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

- Get rid of `coins_minute_` prefix; it clutters the SQL without providing any useful info.
- <strike>Don't specify the time twice -- there are simple functions to convert between `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.</strike>  Why do you have both 'created' and an 'updated' timestamps?  Are you doing `UPDATE` statements?  If so, then the code is more complicated than simply "inserting".  And you need a unique key to know which row to update.
- Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive that what you provided.
- 30 inserts/second is easily handled.  300/sec *may* have issues.
- Do not `PARTITION` the table without some real reason to do so.  The common *valid* reason is that you want to delete 'old' data periodically.  If you are deleting after 3 months, I would build the table with `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` and use weekly partitions.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
- Show us the queries.  A schema cannot be optimized without knowing how it will be accessed.
- "Batch" inserts are much faster than single-row `INSERT` statements.  This can be in the form of `INSERT INTO x (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (11,22), ...` or `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  The latter is very good if you already have a CSV file.
- Does your data come from a single source?  Or 1900 different sources?
- MySQL and MariaDB are probably identical for your task.  (Again, need to see queries.)  PDO is fine for either; no recoding needed.
- After seeing the queries, we can discuss what `PRIMARY KEY` to have and what secondary `INDEX(es)` to have.
- 1 minute vs 5 minutes?  Do you mean that you will gather only one-fifth as many rows in the latter case?  We can discuss this after the rest of the details are brought out.
- That query does not make sense in multiple ways.  Why stop at "1000"?  The output is quite large; what client cares about that much data?  The ordering is indefinite -- the datetime is not guaranteed to be in order.  Why specify the usd without specifying the datetime?  Please provide a rationale query; then I can help you with `INDEX(es)`.

Comment: Regarding the timestampe/datetime, i use datetime to capture the datetime it was created, i use timestamp to show when the row was updated.

The data is provided by one source.

Yes 1 fifth of the queries.

This is one of the queries where i will be using the data from the table that collects data every five minutes

Comment: This is one of the queries which will be used, the others vary from -1day to -90days 

`$sql = " SELECT coins_minute_coin_fk, coins_minute_usd  FROM coins_minutes WHERE coins_minute_datetime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)  AND coins_minute_coin_fk <= 1000  ORDER BY coins_minute_coin_fk ASC ";`

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 - I made some changes and additions.